# Spring MVC - HTTP status code 400 (Bad Request) for missing field when submitting form with dropdown

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using spring mvc with thymeleaf to save a form with a dropdown value. The problem is when saving, I get the error 400 bad request only when I append the foreign key field in the form as a dropdown with `th:field="studentTypeCode"`.

```
<select id="typeSelect" class="text_box" th:field="*{studentTypeCode}">
    <div th:each="studentTypeCode : ${studentTypeCodes}" th:remove="tag">
        <option th:value="${studentTypeCode.typeId}" th:text="${studentTypeCode.typeName}" />
    </div>
</select>
```

Student.java

```
public class Student{
    private String name;
    //... other fields
    //..
    StudentTypeCode studentTypeCode;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And in the controller I get the Student object using the `th:object` with the

`@ModelAttribute Student student` param. Saving the form throws me 400 bad request since the field `studentTypeCode` is not correctly sent in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that since I'm using the `@ModelAttribute` I just need to send the proper value to the Student object with the student type code id. Declaring `th:field="*{studentTypeCode.studentTypeId}"` gives me the exact value(int) selected in the dropdown and I can save this value.

The following code,

```
<select id="typeSelect" class="text_box" th:field="*{studentTypeCode.studentTypeId}">
    <div th:each="studentTypeCode : ${studentTypeCodes}" th:remove="tag">
        <option th:value="${studentTypeCode.typeId}" th:text="${studentTypeCode.typeName}" />
    </div>
</select>
```

solved my issue. Also add the `BindingResult error` after your `@ModelAttribute field` in the `@RequestMapping`. Read more [this article.](https://ellipsistechnology.wordpress.com/2015/12/26/spring-mvc-and-thymeleaf-bad-request/)